# Quantization of a measure of error in SOM

Tags: r, quantization, som, self-organizing-maps

I want to count quantization error (qe) in my SOM model using  R. This is the code I've tried:

```
data(yeast)## take only complete 
x <- yeast[[3]][apply(yeast[[3]], 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) == 0,]
yeast.som <- som(x, somgrid(5, 8, "hexagonal"))
## quantization error:
mean(yeast.som$distances)
```

Is that code right? There exist another method to count qe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right to use `yeast.som$distances` to give an errore measure related to a SOM because it represents the mean distance of the elements from their codebooks. If I had to choose only one feature I would choose that one.

Nevertheless that is not the only one: for example you could compute the number of empty cells (cells that have no elements assigned) starting from `yeast.som$unit.classif`. The lower number of empty cells, the better SOM.

You have also another measure about the distance of each codebook from the other ones. You can see it doing: `plot(yeast.som, type = "quality")`.

A measure of goodness of a SOM could be a combination of the one presented above.